# How to put event into ReactiveX Observable?

Tags: java, listener, rx-java, reactivex

I have an event callback method

```
public void onSomethingHappened(Information info) {
```

which is called by some conventional event issuer.

Now I wish to wrap this into ReactiveX observable.

How to do this?

**UPDATE**

I found [`PublishSubject<T>`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/PublishSubject.html) class and used this in the following way to wrap [`LocationListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) from Android API:

```
public class LocationPublisher implements LocationListener {


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        LocationPublisher.onNext(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        StatusPublisher.onNext( new BundleEx(provider, status, extras) );
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        EnablenessPublisher.onNext(new Enableness(provider, true));
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        EnablenessPublisher.onNext(new Enableness(provider, false));
    }

    public final PublishSubject<Location> LocationPublisher = PublishSubject.create();

    public final PublishSubject<BundleEx> StatusPublisher = PublishSubject.create();

    public final PublishSubject<Enableness> EnablenessPublisher = PublishSubject.create();


    public static class Enableness {

        private final String provider;

        private final boolean enabled;


        public Enableness(String provider, boolean enabled) {
            this.provider = provider;
            this.enabled = enabled;
        }

        public String getProvider() {
            return provider;
        }

        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return enabled;
        }
    }


    public static class BundleEx {

        private final String provider;

        private final int status;

        private final Bundle extras;

        public BundleEx(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            this.provider = provider;
            this.status = status;
            this.extras = extras;
        }

        public String getProvider() {
            return provider;
        }

        public int getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public Bundle getExtras() {
            return extras;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this correct approach? Now I am able to subscribe to `LocationPublisher`, `StatusPublisher` and `EnablenessPublisher` am I?

Comment: You can basically subscribe to any object that implements Observable... So yes, you can subscribe to  all your PublishSubjects object inside LocationPublisher. If it is a good approach? That's hard to say... it looks good for me.

Comment: The problem is that anybody can push values to exposed subjects, and RxJava apparently has not notion of r/o subjects.

Comment: What is an r/o subject??

Answer (score -2):

You would consider the source of these event as the conceptual observable, and the listener is the conceptual subscriber.

The biggest mismatch is that you have an infinite source of events, i.e. it won't terminate on it's own. Not that it is illegal or impossible to deal with, but it is not natural for RX.

So you use Observable.create(). The OnSubscribe is the action that adds the listener to this conventional source, while you implement a listener which calls the subscriber's onNext().

//final EventSource source = ...

```
Observable.create(s -> {
  source.addFooBarListener(info -> { //could be a full anon innerclass too if more than 1 method
    s.onNext(info);
  });
});
```

I go by memory, I don't have a compiler nor apis on hand. sorry.
There are missing code lines to perform the correct onComplete()/onError() of course.